# How do I redirect user who adds "author/admin" to my domain name?

Tags: wordpress

If you type "author/admin" after a wordpress website domain name (ie "mywebsite.com/author/admin") it will show you a list of all articles posted by the admin.  I would like a user to be redirected to the homepage if they try to access this page.

I wanted to do redirect anyone who types in "2016" or "2017" as well.  For example, if someone goes to my website and types in "mywebsite.com/2017" they would normally see a list of all articles from 2017 but I added this code to functions.php that now redirects them to the home page:

```
function redirect_to_home( $query ){
if(is_date() ) {
     wp_redirect( home_url() );
     exit;
 } 
} add_action( 'parse_query', 'redirect_to_home' );
```

If I change the "is_date" portion of that code to "is_author" it redirects the user anytime they type in "author/admin" but I can't figure out how to do both.  I've tried adding two sets of code, one with "is_date" and one with "is_author" but I get a wordpress error when I try to save it.  Is there a way to combine "is_date" and "is_author" into one set of code to redirect users in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

You need || (or) comparison operator:

```
function redirect_to_home( $query ){
   if(is_date() || is_author()) {
       wp_redirect( home_url() );
       exit;
   } 
} add_action( 'parse_query', 'redirect_to_home' );
```

Also have a look here for more comparison operators: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_operators.asp